# Use gevent with selenium to read serveral detail-informations in parallel?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, gevent

i would like to use gevent with selenium to read several detail-pages in parallel using the following code:

```
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()
from gevent.pool import Pool
import time
import os, sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

def work(elem):
  driverDetail = webdriver.Chrome (service=srv, options=options)    
  wName = elem.find("div", {"class": "account-profile-preview-name"}).text.strip()
  wLink = elem.get("href")
  print(f"Working for {wLink}")
  driverDetail.get (wLink)       
  time.sleep(WAIT) 
  soup = BeautifulSoup (driverDetail.page_source, 'lxml')             
  worker = list(soup.find("div", {"class": "therapist-center-bio"}).stripped_strings)
  wDesc = "\n".join(worker)
  tmpRow = [wName, wDesc, wLink] 
  driverDetail.quit()
  return(tmpRow)

if __name__ == '__main__':  
  WAIT = 1
  path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])) 
   
  os.environ['WDM_LOG'] = '0' 
  options = Options()
  options.add_argument('--headless=new')  
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1})    
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled') 
  srv=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
  driver = webdriver.Chrome (service=srv, options=options)    
  waitWD = WebDriverWait (driver, 10)         
  for pageNr in range(0, 2000):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome (service=srv, options=options)    
    waitWD = WebDriverWait (driver, 10)  
    link = f"https://openpathcollective.org/find-a-clinician/?action=search_fetch&pagination={pageNr}&address&distance&remote&online&cost=both&n&specialties&treatment&language&ethnicity&modality&age"

    print(f"Working for {link}")  
    driver.get (link)     
    waitWD.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="search-results"]')))    
    time.sleep(WAIT) 
    soup = BeautifulSoup (driver.page_source, 'lxml')  
    tmpDIV = soup.find("div", {"class": "search-results"})   
    tmpDIV = tmpDIV.find_all("a", {"class": "account-profile-preview"})     
    print(f"{len(tmpDIV)} elements found")

    p = Pool()
    ergList = []
    for wDIV in tmpDIV:
      tmpRow = p.spawn(work, wDIV)
      ergList.append(tmpRow)
    p.join()
    ergList = [x.value for x in ergList]
    print(len(ergList))
    input("Press!")
```

But when i run the code i get the following output:

```
$ python trySelenium.py
Checking Browser driver...
Working for https://openpathcollective.org/find-a-clinician/?action=search_fetch&pagination=0&address&distance&remote&online&cost=both&n&specialties&treatment&language&ethnicity&modality&age
20 elements found
Working for https://openpathcollective.org/clinicians/august-cox/
Working for https://openpathcollective.org/clinicians/karla-peralta/
Working for https://openpathcollective.org/clinicians/kelly-pohlig/
Working for https://openpathcollective.org/clinicians/yuri-otsuka/
Working for https://openpathcollective.org/clinicians/waleed-riaz/
Working for https://openpathcollective.org/clinicians/katie-paddon/
Working for https://openpathcollective.org/clinicians/jingfei-zuo/
Working for https://openpathcollective.org/clinicians/diane-watt/
Working for https://openpathcollective.org/clinicians/sarah-smith/
Working for https://openpathcollective.org/clinicians/jessica-valladares/
Working for https://openpathcollective.org/clinicians/karene-chendo/
Working for https://openpathcollective.org/clinicians/hannah-paduano/
Working for https://openpathcollective.org/clinicians/tiffany-braman/
Working for https://openpathcollective.org/clinicians/teresia-medley-hood/
Working for https://openpathcollective.org/clinicians/tiffany-graziano/
Working for https://openpathcollective.org/clinicians/amna-nawaz/
Working for https://openpathcollective.org/clinicians/douglas-minshall/
Working for https://openpathcollective.org/clinicians/marissa-long/
Working for https://openpathcollective.org/clinicians/anita-kramer/
Working for https://openpathcollective.org/clinicians/eduardo-pino/
['Yuri Otsuka', 'Counselor - LGPC', 'Washington, DC', 'Hello! If you are looking for a therapist, you are probably feeling a bit overwhelemed. Not only is it challenging to look for a therapist that appears good on paper, it’s hard to then 
find someone you can also feel safe and comfortable to talk with about your most intimate thoughts and experiences. I’ve been there. I believe that long-lasting change occurs only when you are provided with a space where you can develop your natural voice, a place where you can consistently expect that you will be listened to without interruption or retaliation, a place where you can learn more deeply about yourself and create a renewed relationship with all the different parts of you. I am committed to creating that space with you in a natural way. Contact me if you have any questions before we get started!', 'Adjustment Disorders, Anxiety, Attachment Issues, Depression, Gender or Sexual Identity Exploration, 
LGBTQ+ (Sexuality), Life Transitions, Mood Disorders, Personality Disorders, Racial Stress & Trauma, Stress, Suicidal Ideation, Transgender and Nonbinary People, Trauma', 'https://openpathcollective.org/clinicians/yuri-otsuka/', 'https://openpathcollective.org/find-a-clinician/?action=search_fetch&pagination=0&address&distance&remote&online&cost=both&n&specialties&treatment&language&ethnicity&modality&age', 0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src\\gevent\\greenlet.py", line 908, in gevent._gevent_cgreenlet.Greenlet.run
  File "G:\DEV\Python-Diverses\gevent\trySelenium.py", line 38, in work
    soup = BeautifulSoup (driverDetail.page_source, 'lxml')
  File "G:\DEV\.venv\selAll\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 550, in page_source
    return self.execute(Command.GET_PAGE_SOURCE)["value"]
  File "G:\DEV\.venv\selAll\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 444, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "G:\DEV\.venv\selAll\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 249, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSessionIdException: Message: invalid session id
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0117A813+48355]
        (No symbol) [0x0110C4B1]
        (No symbol) [0x01015220]
        (No symbol) [0x01037C7C]
        (No symbol) [0x0105A636]
        (No symbol) [0x010570CD]
        (No symbol) [0x01056B3A]
        (No symbol) [0x00FF5311]
        (No symbol) [0x00FF571E]
        (No symbol) [0x00FF5AFA]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x013DAABD+2539405]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0141A78F+2800735]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0141456C+2775612]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x012052AA+616314]
        (No symbol) [0x01115F8C]
        (No symbol) [0x0103794A]
        (No symbol) [0x0105A811]
        (No symbol) [0x010570CD]
        (No symbol) [0x01056B3A]
        (No symbol) [0x00FF5311]
        (No symbol) [0x00FF571E]
        (No symbol) [0x00FF5AFA]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x013DAABD+2539405]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0141A78F+2800735]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0141456C+2775612]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x012051E0+616112]
        (No symbol) [0x01115F8C]
        (No symbol) [0x00FF4F64]
        (No symbol) [0x00FF4912]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0144159C+2959980]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x766C00C9+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x76F07B4E+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x76F07B1E+238]

2023-06-24T06:56:46Z <Greenlet at 0x21695c3cae0: work(<a class="account-profile-preview" href="https://o)> failed with InvalidSessionIdException

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src\\gevent\\greenlet.py", line 908, in gevent._gevent_cgreenlet.Greenlet.run
  File "G:\DEV\Python-Diverses\gevent\trySelenium.py", line 38, in work
    soup = BeautifulSoup (driverDetail.page_source, 'lxml')
  File "G:\DEV\.venv\selAll\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 550, in page_source
    return self.execute(Command.GET_PAGE_SOURCE)["value"]
  File "G:\DEV\.venv\selAll\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 444, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "G:\DEV\.venv\selAll\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 249, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSessionIdException: Message: invalid session id
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0117A813+48355]
        (No symbol) [0x0110C4B1]
        (No symbol) [0x01015220]
        (No symbol) [0x01037C7C]
        (No symbol) [0x0105A636]
        (No symbol) [0x010570CD]
        (No symbol) [0x01056B3A]
        (No symbol) [0x00FF5311]
        (No symbol) [0x00FF571E]
        (No symbol) [0x00FF5AFA]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x013DAABD+2539405]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0141A78F+2800735]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0141456C+2775612]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x012052AA+616314]
        (No symbol) [0x01115F8C]
        (No symbol) [0x0103794A]
        (No symbol) [0x0105A811]
        (No symbol) [0x010570CD]
        (No symbol) [0x01056B3A]
        (No symbol) [0x00FF5311]
        (No symbol) [0x00FF571E]
        (No symbol) [0x00FF5AFA]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x013DAABD+2539405]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0141A78F+2800735]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0141456C+2775612]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x012051E0+616112]
        (No symbol) [0x01115F8C]
        (No symbol) [0x00FF4F64]
        (No symbol) [0x00FF4912]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0144159C+2959980]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x766C00C9+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x76F07B4E+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x76F07B1E+238]

2023-06-24T06:56:47Z <Greenlet at 0x21695c3d120: work(<a class="account-profile-preview" href="https://o)> failed with InvalidSessionIdException

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src\\gevent\\greenlet.py", line 908, in gevent._gevent_cgreenlet.Greenlet.run
  File "G:\DEV\Python-Diverses\gevent\trySelenium.py", line 38, in work
    soup = BeautifulSoup (driverDetail.page_source, 'lxml')
  File "G:\DEV\.venv\selAll\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 550, in page_source
    return self.execute(Command.GET_PAGE_SOURCE)["value"]
  File "G:\DEV\.venv\selAll\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 444, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "G:\DEV\.venv\selAll\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 249, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSessionIdException: Message: invalid session id
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0117A813+48355]
        (No symbol) [0x0110C4B1]
        (No symbol) [0x01015220]
        (No symbol) [0x01037C7C]
        (No symbol) [0x0105A636]
        (No symbol) [0x010570CD]
        (No symbol) [0x01056B3A]
        (No symbol) [0x00FF5311]
        (No symbol) [0x00FF571E]
        (No symbol) [0x00FF5AFA]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x013DAABD+2539405]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0141A78F+2800735]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0141456C+2775612]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x012052AA+616314]
        (No symbol) [0x01115F8C]
        (No symbol) [0x0103794A]
        (No symbol) [0x0105A811]
        (No symbol) [0x010570CD]
        (No symbol) [0x01056B3A]
        (No symbol) [0x00FF5311]
        (No symbol) [0x00FF571E]
        (No symbol) [0x00FF5AFA]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x013DAABD+2539405]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0141A78F+2800735]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0141456C+2775612]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x012051E0+616112]
        (No symbol) [0x01115F8C]
        (No symbol) [0x00FF4F64]
        (No symbol) [0x00FF4912]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0144159C+2959980]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x766C00C9+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x76F07B4E+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x76F07B1E+238]

2023-06-24T06:56:48Z <Greenlet at 0x21695c3c040: work(<a class="account-profile-preview" href="https://o)> failed with InvalidSessionIdException
```

How can i get rid of this error-message and only get the output of the length of the result

```
print(len(ergList))
input("Press!")
```

And i don´t understand why this is outputted at all:

```
['Yuri Otsuka', 'Counselor - LGPC', 'Washington, DC', 'Hello! If you are looking for a therapist, you are probably feeling a bit overwhelemed. Not only is it challenging to look for a therapist that appears good on paper, it’s hard to then 
    find someone you can also feel safe and comfortable to talk with about your most intimate thoughts and experiences. I’ve been there. I believe that long-lasting change occurs only when you are provided with a space where you can develop your natural voice, a place where you can consistently expect that you will be listened to without interruption or retaliation, a place where you can learn more deeply about yourself and create a renewed relationship with all the different parts of you. I am committed to creating that space with you in a natural way. Contact me if you have any questions before we get started!', 'Adjustment Disorders, Anxiety, Attachment Issues, Depression, Gender or Sexual Identity Exploration,
```